# Function should return unique double, instead of an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am creating a function "myFunction" in VBA that should return a unique value of type Double. Inside this function I have a statement `Application.Run("myAddInFunction",...)`, where I call a second function; this second function belongs to an Add-In (this add-in is a black box to me, I can't change it).

This "myAddInFunction" returns an array. Specifically, when debugging, it appears as *"Variant/Variant(1 to 2, 1 to 7)*; in other words, it is a 2x7 matrix. I use values from this array to make some calculations, generate a unique double, and this unique double should be the return to the main "myFunction".

```
Function myFunction(arg1,arg2):

    ' Call add-In Function. It will return a 2x7 matrix
    temp_response = Application.Run("myAddInFunction", arg1, arg2)

    ' Store some specific values from temp_response in new variables
    var1 = temp_response(2, 4)
    var2 = temp_response(2, 5)

    ' Make some calculations using var1 and var2
    myFunction = var1 * var2

End Function
```

PROBLEM: when I call `myFunction` inside cell `A1`, for example, it will return a matrix in the range `A1:G2` (2x7 matrix), where all cells are filled with the Double value given by `myFunction`. I was expecting that only A1 to be filled with this value, not the full range `A1:G2`

THE FUNNIEST: I set a breakpoint inside `myFunction` **AFTER** *Application.Run* command. When I call `myFunction` again (inside A1), the code will stop in the breakpoint. After press <kbd>F5</kbd> to release the code, the function works perfectly, filling only cell `A1` with that Double value!

Is there anybody with any idea of how to overcome this issue? I don't want a array response in `myFunction`, only a Double value inside the cell where I inserted the formula `=myFunction(arg1,arg2)`

Comment: Is `temp_response ` an array? Did you test that using `Debut.Print UBound(temp_response, 1)`?  Do `var1` and `var2` have the expected value? What 'arg1` and `arg2` are? Arrays?

Comment: If you need your function to return a double, you must declare it as `Function myFunction(arg1,arg2) As Double`. But `arg1` and `arg` it is also good to be properly declared. What type they must be?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with a hard-coded 2x7 array. Only a single value is returned to the worksheet.

Comment: This is a stab in the dark, but what does `=@myFunction(...)` return? I don't know why an array would be returned based on the code you've provided though.

Comment: @Caio Brandão: Still alive? What `arg1` and `arg2` are? Ranges?

Comment: "=myFunction(B1,C1)", where B1 and C1 content types are String and Date, respectively

Comment: @Caio Brandão: It doesn't matter what type of data the cells contain. It is good to declare them `As Range`. So, try declaring your function like: `Function myFunction(arg1 As Range, arg2 As Range) As Double` and check if `"myAddInFunction"` does not return **directly in a cells range**. Then check if `var1` and `var2` take values (using `Debut.Print var1, var2` after the line `var2 = temp_response(2, 5)`. Pressing Ctrl + G will  open Immediate Window and you will see their values, if any. If they take values, your function will return a double in the active cell.

Comment: Any other adjacent cells are filled, this has been done by your `myAddInFunction` function...

Comment: Still alive? Do you have some feedback?

Comment: FanDuru thanks for your active helping. It seems "myAddInFunction" is filling the 2x7 cell range. I know this addIn has a third function (let's say "myAddInFunction2"), which doesn't take args and returns a matrix. I repeated the steps with `Function myFunction()` and `Application.Run("myAddInFunction2")`, and the problem persists. So, `arg1' and `arg2` aren't the issue (but I got your best practice tip about declaring them, thanks). Anyway, I guess the solution is to modify the AddIn. The strangest thing is the problem doesn't appear when I insert a breakpoint in the code. 

VBA issues haha